# What does this css stands for?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
div[id^=image]:target{
/*some styles here*/
}
```

I found the above mentioned code part on http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/04/css-image-gallery/ what does this code mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of an [**attribute selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) combined with a `:target` pseudo class.

What this will do is set the given styles on any element with the passed attribute value which is the target of an anchor.

Specifically it identifies any `div` elements with an `id` attribute starting with (`^=`) the string 'image', and sets the style when they are targeted from (e.g.) an anchor.

### [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

To quote MDN (where 'attr' is the attribute being used to select on):

> [attr] Represents an element with an attribute name of attr.
>
> [attr=value] Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and
>   whose value is exactly "value".
>
> [attr~=value] Represents an element
>   with an attribute name of attr whose value is a whitespace-separated
>   list of words, one of which is exactly "value".
>
> [attr|=value]
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr. Its value can be
>   exactly “value” or can begin with “value” immediately followed by “-”
>   (U+002D). It can be used for language subcode matches.
>
> [**attr^=value**]
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value
>   is prefixed by "value".
>
> [attr$=value] Represents an element with an
>   attribute name of attr and whose value is suffixed by "value".
>
> [attr*=value] Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and
>   whose value contains at least one occurrence of string "value" as
>   substring.

As you can see, you can use various operators with attribute selectors in order to identify the precise nature of the attribute value.

### [The `:target` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)

> The `:target` pseudo-class represents the unique element, if any, with
>   an id matching the fragment identifier of the URI of the document..

### Example

```css
div[id^=image]:target {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id='image'>this</div>
<div id='notimage'>not this</div>
<a href='#image'>click me!</a>
```

Comment: Thanks- dont forget to accept (click the tick) if you feel this has provided an answer